# How to export CSV file in Libre Office using separator at the end of last field?

Tags: field, export-to-csv, libreoffice, separator

I have an application which saves CSV files. When I import in Libre Office 5 and save again as CSV, the resulting file will not contain a field separator at the end of the last field.
I could use an awk script but is too hard to use for other users.
Is there any setting in libre office which will allow me to import and save the file successfully?

Comment: Why should a record (line) in CSV include a field separator after the last field? This last field is terminated by the end-of-line.

Comment: Since I use a newer version, I cannot check, but did you look into "Tools - Options - LibreOffice - Advanced - Expert Configuration"? You can filter them for example with the keyword "csv".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the CSV-file that you described corresponds to a table with an empty column with an "invisible heading", usually a space.

Therefore, the easiest and fastest way to do what you want is to add a space in the table header after the last column before exporting.

[image: CSV-end-separator.png]